# In managed C++ how to define generic method that returns a value of specified type

Tags: c++-cli, managed

I am trying to declare an equivalent of this code in c#:

```
public T FieldValueOrDefault<T>(int columnIndex);
```

I am using managed C++ Visual Studio 2015. If it matters, Target Platform Version is set to 8.1 and CLR Support set to /clr. When I enter something like this:

```
generic<typename T>
T FieldValueOrDefault<T>(String^ columnName);
```

I get a compiler error "Error C2768 FieldValueOrDefault': illegal use of explicit template arguments"

Please let me know what is a correct way to declare such thing.

Comment: I am new to managed C++. Mostly worked with C# before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be, as pointed out [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssea4yk6.aspx):

```
generic<typename T>
T FieldValueOrDefault(String^ columnName);
```

The `<T>` is superfluous.